# Extracting a particular range of bits and find number of zeros between them in C

Tags: c

I want to extract a particular range of bits in an integer variable.

For example: 0xA5 (10100101)

I want to extract from bit2 to bit5. i.e 1001 to a variable and count number of zeros between them.

I have another variable which give the starting point, which means in this case the value of the variable is 2. So the starting point can be find by 0xA5 >> 2.
5th bit position is a random position here..means it can be 6 or 7. The main idea is whichever bit is set to 1 after 2nd bit. I have to extract that..

How can I do rest of the part ?

Comment: Do you know about *bit masking*? About the *bitwise **and** operator `&`*?

Comment: For a certain value I know how to extract. But during runtime how we can extract...

Comment: Use a variable as the mask? And assign the correct mask to the variable at runtime? Same with the shifting, use variables.

Comment: You can iterate over different masks during runtime, such that the masks check all the bit positions in the number under test.

Comment: If those int vars are restricted to one byte, an alternative approach could be to use a const lookup table to get the appropriate mask.

Comment: ..though it's prolly easier to just shift up a 1-bit mask and use it to count the zeros, as suggested by others.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are dealing with `unsigned int` for your variable. 
You will have to construct the appropriate mask.

Suppose you want the bits from position `x` to position `y`, there need to be `y - x + 1` `1s` in the mask.

You can get this by -

```
int digits = y - x + 1;
unsigned int mask = 1u << digits - 1;
```

Now you need to remove the lower `x` bits from the initial number, which be done by -

```
unsigned int result = number >> x;
```

Finally apply the mask to remove the upper bits -

```
result = result & mask;
```

Comment: Here the position y can change. Basically what I meant is number of zeros from xth position to the next position which having value 1.

Comment: @Salim your question doesn't make that clear. I think you should post it as a separate question showing the details properly, because this has been adequately answered by a lot of users.

Comment: @Ayan : I have already this in my question "The main idea is whichever bit is set to 1 after 2nd bit. I have to extract that.."

Comment: I don't know the exact edit time, but the question has changed significantly after the edit. I strongly suggest posting a separate question. I can edit my answer to accommodate your change, but it wouldn't be fair to other answers and leave those answers not coherent with the new version of the question. You can roll back this question and then post a new question. I am sure nobody would mind similar but different questions. Just make sure you make the intent clear with adequate examples and/or clearly worded description.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mask and the "&" (AND) operation:

```
a = 0xA5;
a = a >> OFFSET; //OFFSET 
mask = 0x0F; // equals 00001111
a = a & mask;
```

In your example a = 0xA5 (10100101), and the offset is 2.

- a >> 2 a now equals to 0x29 (00101001)
- a & 0x0F (00101001 AND
  00001111) = 00001001 = 0x09

Comment: `&&` is the logical and, the bitwise and is `&`.

Comment: First of all, bits 2 to 5 are *four* bits. Secondly, you're using the *logical* and operator. The result of `a && mask` will be `1`, *always*.

Answer (score 1):

In this example we put 0 or 1 values into array. After that you can treat array as you like.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    uint8_t value = 0xA5;
    unsigned char bytes[8];
    unsigned char i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        bytes[i] = (value & (1 << i)) != 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%d", bytes[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want bits from the offset `X` then shift right by `X`.

If you want `Y` bits, then then mask (after the shift) will be 2 to the power of `Y` minus one (for your example with four bits, 2 to the power of 4 is 16, minus one is 15 which is `1111` binary). This can be dome by using left-shifting by `Y` bits and subtracting `1`.

However, the masking isn't needed if you want to count the number of zeros in the wanted bits, only the right shift. Loop `Y` times, each time shifting a `1` left one step, and check using bitwise and if the value is zero. If it is then increment a counter. At the end of the loop the counter is the number of zeros.

---

To put it all in code:

```
// Count the number of zeros in a specific amount of bits starting at a specific offset
// value is the original value
// offset is the offset in bits
// bits is the number of bits to check
unsigned int count_zeros(unsigned int value, unsigned int offset, unsigned int bits)
{
    // Get the bits we're interested in the rightmost position
    value >>= offset;

    unsigned int counter = 0;  // Zero-counter
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bits; ++i)
    {
        if ((value & (1 << i)) == 0)
        {
            ++counter;  // Bit is a zero
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

To use with the example data you have:

```
count_zeros(0xa5, 2, 4);
```

The result should be `2`. Which it is [if you see this live program](https://ideone.com/bEujqx).

Comment: Actually we dont have any control on variable "bits". I mean it can be 4,5... But it is postion of the next 1 after shifting with the offset

Comment: If your aim is extract the first set bit after `offset` bit, simply use `while(value)` and check each bit if it is set or not. When bit is set break, else continue the loop.

Comment: @Salim When you say "position of the next 1", you don't mean the first `1` bit? Because then with the input `0xa5` we would count only one bit (since bit 0 is `1`). What are the rules for "next 1"? If you have `1001` (as in your example) it's the *second* `1`, but what if you have `1010`? Or `1100`? Or `1000`? Please edit your question to elaborate on the actual, specific and all requirements. And if possible add more examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
int32_t do_test(int32_t value, int32_t offset)
{
    int32_t _zeros = 1;
    value >>= offset;    

    int i = 1;

    while(1) {
        if((value >> i) % 2 == 0) {
            _zeros += 1;
            i++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the problem you mention, there is a solution possible without actually using loops. Just so you know.

Comment: @Ayan How can we  do without loops ?

Comment: Like I said before, you need to ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = (0xA5 >> 2) & 0x0F;
```

Truth table for the `&` operator

```
 |    INPUTS  | OUTPUT |
 -----------------------
 |  0   |  0  |    0   |
 |  0   |  1  |    0   |
 |  1   |  0  |    0   |  
 |  1   |  1  |    1   |
 -----------------------
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: this is for a particular example. I want do it for random values. Istead of 5th posiotion it can be 6th also